# Post-apocalyptic industrial production

Tags: science-based, technology, post-apocalypse

It's 2100. About 50 years ago, modern civilization collapsed after a decade of turmoil caused by the depletion of oil reserves, pollution, global warming, erosion of arable land, increasing military strife over the remaining resources. Masses of people fled starvation, conflict anywhere resembling safety, and increasingly hostile environment, mainly by foot, and the majority didn't get too far. At some point, nuclear weapons entered the picture, but they were mainly used against choice targets in great powers; most of the large cities didn't need much outside help in dying and collapsed in disease, struggle for survival and survivors fleeing for countryside.

Global population has fallen by at least 90%. There's been enough time for the surplus population to die off and for nature and civilisation to recover a bit from the shockwaves. While the trauma to collective mind and loss of life has been enormous, society has established itself where it can and the circumstances, while still harsh, have stabilised a bit.

Fossile fuels, save for possibly coal, are not widely available. Forests, while depleted, are, as are remnants of old power plants etc.

To what extent and what kind of energy infrastructure could you run in those circumstances? I'm assuming you couldn't really use modern wind or solar power due to lack of rare metals needed in maintaining them, but could you use/modify/maintain hydropower plants or make use of coal, firewood or some other resource to run some kind of industrial base?

Keep in mind that there has been quite serious a loss of knowledge and experience in multiple fields, and the majority of people are employed in agriculture now. Experts, while they exist, are rare and usually not as well read as their modern equivalents. Petroleum is absolutely not an option.

Could you run a small clothing factory for example with that alone? Even produce some steam boats, or anything like a mining industry with basic railroads?

Comment: *"Except possibly coal":" There is plenty of coal on Earth, enough to last for many many centuries. There will always be coal.  Iron and coal are so plentiful on Earth, so 19th century technology will always be available.Now, *where* exactly will that coal be, that may be a problem. Surprisingly, I cannot see how we could possibly run out of petroleum in 30 years; there is lots of the stuff available. Hydropower will always be available, obviously. Books live happily in whatever house is good is enough for people. But the last paragraph is the clicker: barbarians are barbaric.

Comment: @AlexP: The problem is not running out of coal (or other fossil fuels), it's that if it's all burned, we run out of habitable biosphere.

Comment: Not running out of oil, but running out of oil that can be reached easily enough to make it economically feasible. Peak oil scenario, really, along with other disasters, and once complex systems start failing, I'd expect them to fail spectacularly.

Comment: @jamesqf: The question posits a nuclear war and a human population reduced to 10% of what it is now. Under such conditions global warming won't be a significant problem for a very very long time.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding! That's a lot of questions you've asked, so it might help you to get better answers if you split this post up into multiple posts asking each (specific) question in a single post, linking each post

Comment: Yeah that might be necessary. Will do that later on.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad.  See also [other questions with the post-apocalypse tag](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post-apocalypse) for the many, many similar questions that have already been answered.

Comment: 10% of six billion is still 600 million people. That is the total world population in 1850. So yes, civilization would survive. We had all of the institutions you mentioned in 1850. The technology would be similar, too.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Worldbuilding. As previously mentioned, there are too many questions in this post. I have to vote to close as 'too broad'. It seems like there are some good questions in here. Please edit it down to one question. If the question gets closed, your edits will automatically put it into review to be re-opened.

Comment: @AlexP: It would. Even neglecting the effects of the war (large fires &c), there's already enough CO2 to present a problem.  Adding more just makes things worse.